# how to count number of rows inserted or updated in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a ssis project used to inserting large number of rows from table or excel sheet in a table.i want to know how many number of rows are inserted in table while my project is running which function I need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the **ROW COUNT** :

Firstly create a variable in your package in my case i called the variable **ROWNUM**

Secondly add the component **ROW COUNT** in your data flow see the picture as bellow :

[image: ROW COUNT Component]

Double click in the `Row count component` and in `Component properties tab` go to `Variable Name` and select your variable.

Thirdly add a script task see the picture as bellow

[image: Script task]

Double click in the `Script task component` and you will see `ReadonlyVariable` and select your variable then click in the `Edit script` you will see a `Main method` and write the line code as bellow :

```
 public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            MessageBox.Show("Rows inserts are "+Dts.Variables["User::ROWNUM"].Value.ToString()+" rows ");
        }
```